# Can External Credentials be used with Lightning Platform licenses?

Tags: namedcredentials, platform-license

We're using invocable Apex with Named Credentials and External Credentials to handle authentication. However, it seems that without granting "View All" to the object `User External Credential`, the External Credential is not available. This permission is not available to the Lightning Platform license type. Is there another way to allow Lightning Platform users to use External Credentials?

Steps I've taken:

1. External Credential is mapped via permission set
2. Permission set does not have a license type associated with it, and is assigned to both users with Salesforce licenses and Platform licenses
3. If a Salesforce licensed user is assigned "View All" on `User External Credential`, then the Apex callout works. It fails otherwise
4. Since this is invocable Apex, I've tried running the Flow in System mode, ignoring sharing rules. This did not work.
5. I've tried declaring my Apex class `without sharing`. This did not work.

The [documentation for User External Credentials](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.nc_user_external_credentials.htm&type=5) for **Enable User External Credentials Through Permission Sets** says the following. There is no mention of limitations based on license type.

> 1. From Setup, in the Quick Find box, enter permission sets, and then select Permission Sets.
> 2. Click the permission set for which you want to enable user external credentials.
> 3. Under Apps, click Object Settings.
> 4. Click User External Credentials.
> 5. Click Edit, and assign the permissions that you want.
> 6. Save the settings.

Comment: The new [integration user license](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_api_integration_license.htm&release=242&type=5) should obviate the need to jump through hoops with e.g. Lightning Platform. 5 integration users licenses are included at no cost in Ent or higher editions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of March 1, 2023, "View All" on `User External Credential` is a required permission as confirmed by Salesforce Support. This permission is not available to Lightning Platform licenses, so they are unable to use this feature.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this in a sandbox and was able to make a Flow-invoked callout as a Community User (not Lightning Platform I realise) using External Credentials and a Perm Set with:
Create, Read, Edit, Delete
(no View All / Modify All)
on User External Credentials

Here's what I did:

1. Create External Credential - custom type
2. Create Named Credential and add External Credential
3. Create Perm Set with CRED on User External Credentials
4. Add Community User to Perm Set
5. Add Perm Set to External Credential with some auth params
6. Invoke Flow as User
7. Confirm successful callout (response code: 200, returned expected payload)

Comment: I’ll have to re-test that particular example.

Comment: Any update @MikeChale ?